# How to restore Collapsing Toolbar Layout State after screen orientation change

Tags: android, layout, toolbar, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I've been searching for the solution of my problem for some time and didn't find solution.

I want to restore my fragment's layout after screen orientation change. I have Collapsing Toolbar Layout with banner image. After screen rotation my toolbar is always expanded, I want to restore it's behavior. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 153):

You should set **ID** to the **CoordinatorLayout**. It will automatically save its state. Believe me.

[See here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=182062#c8).

Comment: Incredible I've found your answer. And it's the same behavior for NestedScrollView. If I don't set an ID for it the RecyclerView under it doesn't save position either.

Comment: Yes @MárcioOliveira, in my case, I was setting ID to the NestedScrollView, so it keeps the state, but the collapsing toolbar does not.
That's the correct answer

Comment: Good answer. Easy to forget that android saves state of views having id attached to them.

Comment: I realized adding id to AppBarLayout is also required.

Comment: This should be set as such by default, including a warning. Here, made a request for it: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/141918364

Comment: I have set id for all but for me it's still not working. Can you help me out ?

Comment: what about when using navigation component and the view is recreated?

Comment: I cannot believe it is designed this way. Why is this not an lint?

Comment: Remember, you have to add `id` to the `appBar` and `CollapsingToolbar` too, not just the coordinator

Answer (score 7):

set id for both `Coordinatorlayout` and `AppbarLayout`.

setting id for `Coordinatorlayout` was not enough , after adding id to `AppbarLayout` it worked fine

Answer (score 1):

Try using the following AppBarLayout method:

```
public void setExpanded (boolean expanded)
```

However, [there's an Android issue addressing the behavior you reported](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=182062)