# Collapsing Toolbar Layout always expanded when returned from fragment

Tags: android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-appbarlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I have 2 fragments (Fragment A and Fragment B) both with collapsing toolbar layouts and corresponding recyclerviews within a coordinatorlayout.

If I scroll up in my recyclerview (so the CollapsingToolbarLayout has collapsed) and then open Fragment B from fragment A (Pushing A onto the backstack).

When I return to fragment A by hitting back. The CollapsingToolbarLayout/AppBarLayout is always expanded, even though the recycler view is in the same position.

Anyone experience this?

Answer (score 5):

There's a issue related to this.
According to [Chris Banes.](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37054303)

Add these lines inside **onViewCreated()** of your fragment to solve the issue.

```
ViewCompat.requestApplyInsets(mCoordinatorLayout);
```

Comment: Explain what you did?

Answer (score 3):

It's an old question but none of the answers it's correct. I found this other question where they fixed the problem:

[How to restore Collapsing Toolbar Layout State after screen orientation change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32563300/how-to-restore-collapsing-toolbar-layout-state-after-screen-orientation-change)

You have to set an id to your views in order to restore their state automatically.

Answer (score 2):

Today, to fix this issue you only have to set an id to your coordinator layout to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

I had face same problem so i write below code:-

```
private boolean isExpand = true;
private void setTitleNotExpand(boolean isExpand) {
    if(getFragmentViewHolder() != null) {
        this.isExpand = isExpand;
        // AppBarLayout variable
        getFragmentViewHolder().appbar.setExpanded(isExpand);
    }
}
```

when you do add back stack then write below code :-

```
// write below code where you want to stick your toolbar
setTitleNotExpand(false);


// write below code where you want not to stick your toolbar
setTitleNotExpand(true);
```

on your `onFragmentViewHolderCreated` write below code :-

```
getFragmentViewHolder().appbar.setExpanded(isExpand);
```

Answer (score 1):

another thing to consider is that views cannot restore their state if they don't have an id